# How to have customized control templates across multiple pages for .NET MAUI?

Tags: xaml, controls, maui, .net-maui

I am follwing the guide for Control Templates here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/controltemplate

But I want to be able to use my Control Templates across different pages rather than on a single page. I have put the control template in its own folder but when implementing it on a different page, it is not showing up. The example in the website above copies code over from the templated controls to multiple pages which overall increases the amount of code per page. I want to have my custom controls in one folder and then access those controls on different pages without having to copy and paste the control xaml code in that page. Please guide me to some concrete examples of this in action! Thank you!

Comment: please post the relevant code to demonstrate what you have already tried

Comment: "...copies code over from the templated controls to multiple pages.." I don't get this part. Rather than asking for concrete examples, it is better to show what you have so far (code) to help you with "...but when implementing it on a different page, it is not showing up.."

Comment: *"The example in the website above copies code over from the templated controls to multiple pages"* - For simplicity, each example is self-contained. **See the paragraph:** *"While a ControlTemplate can be defined inline, the typical approach to declaring a ControlTemplate is as a resource in a resource dictionary. ... For example, if you declare a control template in your app-level resource dictionary, the template can be used anywhere in your app. ... see [Resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries)."*